# Create HTML table using jQuery and JSON array (Rows Error undefined)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Wax.png)I'm trying to populate the data in the html table with jquery and all columns get undefined error

Html:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>2</th>
                <th>3</th>
                <th>4</th>
                <th>5</th>
                <th>6</th>
                <th>7</th>
              
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
 </table>
```

with the following instruction jquery

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
  
                    // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE
                    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8089/projectw/ServletJSON", function (data) {
                        var e= "";
  
                        // ITERATING THROUGH OBJECTS
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
  
                            //CONSTRUCTION OF ROWS HAVING
                            // DATA FROM JSON OBJECT
                            e += '<tr>'; 
                            e += '<td>' + value.ag + '</td>';
                            e += '<td>' + value.pa + '</td>';
                            e += '<td>' + value.ex + '</td>';
                            e += '<td>' +  value.em + '</td>';             
                            e += '<td>' +  value.at + '</td>';                
                            e += '<td>' + value.ct + '</td>';
                            e += '<td>' +  value.num_ex + '</td>';
                            e += '</tr>';
                        });
                          
                        //INSERTING ROWS INTO TABLE 
                        $('#example').append(e);
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

json example in servlet:

```
{
  "JsonTest": [
    {
      "ag": "RAX",
      "pa": "pa 1",
      "ex": "RXTT",
      "em": "ME",
      "at": 1,
      "ct": 0,
      "num_ex": "1"
    },
    {
      "ag": "TOM",
      "pa": "pa 2",
      "ex": "TOCC",
      "em": "MB",
      "at": 0,
      "ct": 0,
      "num_ex": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Observation If I order to display the json text
(

```
     var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
     req.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8089/projectw/ServletJSON', true);
     req.send();
     req.onload = function(){
     var json=JSON.parse(req.responseText);
     document.getElementsByClassName('message(class of table example)')[0].innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json)
```

),
I get success but to populate the table no.
how could i adjust this?
thank you all !

Expected lines to be filled with json values, no errors in console.

Comment: What is the error message? There is no such thing as an “undefined error” or as an “Error undefined”. Do the table cells just get _populated_ with the _value_ `undefined`?

Comment: the rows stay  = undefined and do not bring the json values

Comment: the error is attached

Comment: So it’s _not_ an error. Have you tried _inspecting_ what the values are before just inserting them into table rows? Try using your browser’s [debug capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a). For example, what does `console.log({ data, key, value });` reveal?

Comment: where would be the best place to put it?
Why putting it below the $.each(data, function (key, value) {
It returns me all the json array present in the Servlet URL as per the example

Comment: no errors unfortunately... just displays the values present in the json array in the console

Comment: Seriously, have a look at using something like https://handlebarsjs.com/ it will make your life a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

If you add a simple `console.log()` to your code to show what `key` and `value` are inside your loop, the problem is immediately obvious:

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    console.log('key is', key, 'value is', value);
    // ... your code ...
});
```

The console shows:

> key is JsonTest value is [
> {
> "ag": "RAX",
> "pa": "pa 1",
> .... etc

And looking at your JSON object it is obvious - you have just 1 top level key, `JsonTest`, all your real data is nested under that.  You want to be iterating over `data.JsonTest`, not `data`.  Here's a simplified working example with that error fixed:

```js
let data = {
    "JsonTest": [
        {
            "ag": "RAX",
            "pa": "pa 1",
            "ex": "RXTT",
            "em": "ME",
            "at": 1,
            "ct": 0,
            "num_ex": "1"
        },
        {
            "ag": "TOM",
            "pa": "pa 2",
            "ex": "TOCC",
            "em": "MB",
            "at": 0,
            "ct": 0,
            "num_ex": "2"
        }
    ]
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    populateTable(data);

    function populateTable(data) {
        var e= "";
        let jsontest = data.JsonTest;

        // ITERATING THROUGH OBJECTS
        $.each(jsontest, function (key, value) {
        
            console.log('key is', key, 'value is', value);

            //CONSTRUCTION OF ROWS HAVING
            // DATA FROM JSON OBJECT
            e += '<tr>';
            e += '<td>' + value.ag + '</td>';
            e += '<td>' + value.pa + '</td>';
            e += '<td>' + value.ex + '</td>';
            e += '<td>' +  value.em + '</td>';
            e += '<td>' +  value.at + '</td>';
            e += '<td>' + value.ct + '</td>';
            e += '<td>' +  value.num_ex + '</td>';
            e += '</tr>';
        });

        //INSERTING ROWS INTO TABLE
        $('#example').append(e);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

You really need to learn to do basic debugging - using your console is the first step in writing Javascript.

Note under SO guidelines I think this question should be considered a typo, and it is not likely to be useful to future visitors.  I have voted to close as a typo.

Comment: How would it look in the current code?
Thus:


      let data = $.getJSON("http://localhost:8089/projectw/ServletJSON", function () {
                         populateTable(data);
                         function populateTable(data) {
                         var e= "";
                         let jsontest = data.e;

Comment: That way you still keep the undefined let ou var ou anything

Comment: It would look exactly the same in your code as in mine.  Do you understand the issue?  `data.JsonTest` is where your array of data is, that's the element you want to iterate over.  Don't iterate over `data`, iterate over `data.JsonTest`.  "*That way you still keep the undefined let ou var ou anything*" I don't understand what this means.

Comment: Sorry, in JS I don't have much understanding so I questioned again because changing the informed form exactly I got the undefined

Comment: Instead of `$.each(data,...`, use `$.each(data.JsonTest,...`.  That's the only change you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I changed the information and got the correct result:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON URL
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:8089/projectw/ServletJSON", function (data) {
    var e= "";
    let jsonTest= data.jsonTest; 
  });
});
```

I believe it can help other dev because the forum contains more questions with JSON files and the few with the use of URL!

Comment: and also in an informed way is correct, I had not understood !

Comment: If you want to leave the question open, this answer does not work, unless you also update the `$.each()` line, as in my code.